# Term for ability to "keep cards close to your chest"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a succinct term or phrase that would describes someone's ability to "keep cards close to their chest", as in, able to subtlety keep things secret.

For context, I'm working on a game where part of it is being able to determine your enemies' strengths and weaknesses (via "perception") and need a term for the attribute which counters perception to keep your strengths and weaknesses concealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Discreet* fits the bill.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discreet)

> adjective
>
> 1 Careful and prudent in one's speech or actions, especially in order
> to keep something confidential or to avoid embarrassment.

If a quality of character is needed, *discretion* would be the word.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discretion)

> noun
>
> 1The quality of behaving or speaking in such a way as to avoid causing
> offence or revealing confidential information.
>
> *She knew she could rely on his discretion*

Comment: Ah, "discretion" works quite well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**guarded**

If you describe someone as **guarded**, you mean that they are careful not to show their feelings or give away information.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/guarded